# Static linking creates Segmentation Fault error

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, static-linking, libgcrypt

I have a problem linking my C application statically. All libraries exist (.a) and just a month ago I was able to static link my application without an error. But as soon as I activate the static linking option in eclipse, I can compile without an error but when I try to run it, I receive an "Segmentation Error" and it stops.

I tried to debug and that is what eclipse is showing me:

```
No source available for "_start() at 0x4017f7"
No source available for "__libc_start_main() at 0x522389"
No source available for "__libc_csu_init() at 0x5228f7"
No source available for "frame_dummy() at 0x4018bd" 
No source available for "__register_frame_info_bases() at 0x52194b" 
No source available for "0x0"
```

I use the following libraries: -lgcrypt -lgpg-error -lmxml -lpthread -lrt. Any ideas what the problem could be? I can also post the gdb traces, but its long.

Linker command:
Invoking: Invoking: GCC C Linker
gcc -static -o "X - Client"  ./src/lib/stopwatch-0.2/stopwatch.o  ./src/lib/rscode-1.3/berlekamp.o ./src/lib/rscode-1.3/crcgen.o ./src/lib/rscode-1.3/galois.o ./src/lib/rscode-1.3/rs.o  ./src/lib/Salsa20/ecrypt.o  ./src/lib/helper-Client.o  ./src/PoR-Client.o   -lgcrypt -lgpg-error -lmxml -lpthread -lrt
Finished building target: X - Client

Comment: "But as soon as I activate the static linking option in eclipse" how you did this? from where you have enabled option?

Comment: Properties -> C/C++ Build -> Settings -> GCC C Linker: General -> Activate "No shared libraries (-static)

Comment: Please, post the result linker command.

Comment: Have you try a clean and build?

Comment: Yes I tried to clean and build. I even installed it on a different computer and compiled it with the same result. I added the linker command to my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably not a problem with the linking. You probably have a problem with reading uninitialized memory, or reading and writing past the end of an array.

What happens in such cases is that on one build the memory you are reading just happens to be set to a non-crashing value ( e.g. you read past the end of an array into an area that has zeroes ), but then in another build the data structures are in a different order and now you are reading from something with unexpected values.

Or you could in one build be writing past the end into a data structure that you don't need any more, and this build, the thing past the end of the array is critical.

Also check if your program runs differently on debug vs. optimized builds. Optimization changes the layout, padding and initialization of data structures. ( e.g. debug builds will for example typically zero all memory, and stack frames are padded out with debugging data ).

I strongly suggest you run your program through a tool like valgrind. It will find these kinds of problems for you.

Comment: You were right! I did not use Valgrind to find my problem, instead I just commented everything out and I found the problem in a single row where I use the mxml library. Now I just need to understand how to solve it but the linker problem is solved!

Comment: Final solution: the mxml library crashes with the mentioned error when -lpthread is used. Bug is reported and my program is running!